# Graphical demos only show on display connected to rpi. I want to see them headless (on my mac pro)

Tags: remote

I can access my rpi on my mac pro via ssh and Microsoft Remote Desktop.
However, when I try to run the demos such as hello_teapot it will only display on the monitor connected to the HDMI connector...not thru MRD onto my mac display.  So I get a new session...not the initial session on bootup. Can I connect to the original session...or is the display programming only using the HDMI port?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: AFAIK these demos work directly on the GPU, so will only work on a monitor. PS Why use Microsoft Remote Desktop? VNC works on all platforms, and you don't need a client on the Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will never show up on anything remote (like your mac). It has nothing to do with the fact that you're using HDMI. It's just how the Pi (or the program) works. The GPU (or the program using the GPU) draws directly on the screen, therefore, VNC or any other remote desktop solutions won't work.

Here's another person experiencing almost the exact same issue: [Minecraft-pi on headless pi using ssh -X](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/39018/24224)