# Minecraft pi, black windows, what to do?

Tags: pi-3, vnc, minecraft

I tried to launch Minecraft Pi, I get a black window and nothing else happens. I'm using the pi-3 remotely with a VNC client, could it be related ? I'm new to Raspberry. I read that overscan enabled is sometimes the problem, disabled it, rebooted, nothing changed.

Comment: See also https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/39018/5538

Answer (score 3):

<strike>RealVNC server for Raspberry Pi does not support Minecraft Pi nor other OpenGL ES programs.</strike>

Some time ago RealVNC released an alpha build...

This is now available in the default installation on Raspbian. The option for "Experimental direct capture mode" can be found under the "Troubleshooting" menu (Thanks Andrew!).

Performance improved after the earlier alpha, and may make Minecraft Pi Edition reasonably playable.

**Moreover**, the inability of regular VNC clients to capture GLES rendering turns out to be specific to the legacy Broadcom GLES driver with dispmanx. The open-source Mesa driver is now the default on Raspberry Pi 4, and for earlier models it can be enabled from

```
sudo raspi-config
```

RealVNC, TigerVNC, and other VNC servers work--without requiring framebuffer capture--in Minecraft's Mesa GLES rendering mode.

Links:

- [Minecraft Pi (and more) over VNC - Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/minecraft-pi-and-more-over-vnc/)
- [Raspberry Pi | RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/en/raspberrypi/)

Comment: In fact, I'm using TightVNC not RealVNC, but that's problably the same kind of problem, isn't it?

Comment: The direct capture mode in RealVNC was released over a year ago, and the speed has improved quite a bit from the original alpha version. You simply need to enable "Experimental direct capture mode" from the VNC Server options, under "Troubleshooting". See https://www.realvnc.com/en/raspberrypi/ for more info.